# Campo calculado com EF

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-6

Tenho duas classes :

```
 public class Cliente 
 {
      public int Id {get;set;
      public string Nome { get; set; }
      public string Email { get; set; }
      public string Telefone { get; set; }
      public string Celular { get; set; }
      public virtual ICollection<Veiculo> Veiculos { get; set; }
 }

 public class Veiculo
 {
    public string Marca { get; set; }
    public string Modelo { get; set; }
    public int Ano { get; private set; }
    public string Placa { get; set; }
 }
```

Gostaria de fazer uma consulta com EF para pegar a quantidade de veiculos para cada cliente. Em uma única consulta.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Supondo que `Clientes` seja o `DbSet` de `Cliente` e `db` seja o contexto de dados

Somar todos os veículos do cliente 1

```
var qtdVeiculos = db.Clientes.Find(1).Veiculos.Count();
```

Ou

```
var qtdVeiculos = db.Veiculos.Count(v => v.IdCliente == 1);
```

Ou com os dados do cliente junto

Obviamente só vai funcionar se existir a propriedade `ClienteId` no model `Veiculo`

```
var model = db.Clientes.Select(c => new
                              {
                                  c.Nome,
                                  QtdVeiculos = c.Veiculos.Count()
                              });
```